# Update DBInstance attribute that requires replacement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

How do I change an attribute of an `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` that [`Requires: Replacement`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html), while preserving all of the data in it. If I provide a snapshot of my db instance and change DBName property in a single stack update process, then I get this error in my cloudformation console:

```
DBName must be null when Restoring for this Engine. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: b494131a-8d8b-44e1-b1d4-ff8d631c182a; Proxy: null)
```

My DBInstance template looks like this:

```
  DBInstance:
    DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Snapshot
    Type: 'AWS::RDS::DBInstance'
    Properties:
      AllocatedStorage: !Ref DBAllocatedStorage
      DBName: !Ref DBInstanceName
      DBSnapshotIdentifier:
        !If [
          HasDBSnapshotIdentifier,
          !Ref DBSnapshotIdentifier,
          !Ref 'AWS::NoValue',
        ]
      MasterUsername: !Ref DBMasterUsername
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref DBMasterUserPassword
      DBParameterGroupName:
        !If [
          HasDBParameterGroupName,
          !Ref DBParameterGroupName,
          !Ref 'AWS::NoValue',
        ]
      OptionGroupName:
        !If [HasDBOptionGroupName, !Ref DBOptionGroupName, !Ref 'AWS::NoValue']
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 14
      CopyTagsToSnapshot: true
      DBInstanceClass: 'db.t3.micro'
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup
      EnableIAMDatabaseAuthentication: true
      Engine: 'postgres'
      EngineVersion: '13.1'
      PreferredBackupWindow: !Ref PreferredBackupWindow
      PreferredMaintenanceWindow: !Ref PreferredMaintenanceWindow
      StorageType: gp2
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref DBInstanceSecurityGroup
```

The error message makes sense, but the problem still stays. **How do I change an attribute of an `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` that Requires: Replacement, while preserving all of the data in it.**

Answer (score 1):

RDS will not rename a database for you. It will only create a new, blank database with the new name.

Why do you need to do this through CloudFormation? This is more of a database maintenance task that should be performed by connecting to the database and running an `ALTER DATABASE RENAME TO` statement.

The only purpose of specifying a DB name to RDS is to have it create an initial, empty database for you so you can immediately start using it. After it's created RDS doesn't care about the DB name any more. You can also create more databases with other names inside the RDS instance.

Answer (score 1):

We can't preserve data for those RDS instances that require replacement, how ever we can restore the data from old one. Here are the steps.

- Disable applications talking to current RDS instance.
- Create a manual snapshot of the RDS instance.
- Modify Cloudformation template [AWS::RDS::DBInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html) to include [DBSnapshotIdentifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbsnapshotidentifier)
- Update Stack, this will not create a new RDS instance with new changes and restore data from the snapshot
- Even for future updates we need to specify same Snapshot identifier.